# Dataflow- dynamic create disposition Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I want to dynamically choose from Create Disposition options depending on the arguments.
In the the DataflowPipelineOptions I am accepting load type in a ValueProvider via arguments. However I am not able to get the string from the ValueProvider to decide on what create disposition option to use.

```
withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
```

I want 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED' to be dynamic. I want to replace this with something like this. Note following is just a pseudocode. I am looking for solution here.

```
create_disp = options.getLoad()
withCreateDisposition(create_disp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a program argument representing `createDisposition`

Program argument (CREATE_NEVER or CREATE_IF_NEEDED) :

```
--bqCreateDisposition=CREATE_NEVER
```

In the Option class in `Java`, you can pass a field as Enum (there is a default value in this case with CREATE_IF_NEEDED) :

```java
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Default;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Default.Enum;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;

public interface MyOptions extends PipelineOptions {

    @Description("BQ create disposition")
    @Default
    @Enum("CREATE_IF_NEEDED")
    BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition getBqCreateDisposition();

    void setBqCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition value);
}
```

Comment: But how can I convert the string I pass in the dataflow command, into Enum? For example: ```--bqCreateDisposition=CREATE_NEVER ``` Here 'CREATE-'NEVER' is a string.

Comment: The String is converted automatically to the expected Enum in this case. The program argument (as String) should have the same value as the Enum, ˋCREATE_NEVER` or `CREATE_IF_NEEDED`

Comment: ```@Enum("CREATE_IF_NEEDED")``` this part of the code throws error ```Enum is not an annotation type```

Comment: I added code imports in the intial post, can you try with these imports please ?

Comment: Yes that is fixed. Thanks. let me run and see if that works.